# Duplicate rows and return a table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an array of strings (Ids) in my C#.

I want to send it to a Procedure in sql-server and duplicate all the rows that their ids are found in the array (but let them new Id and name).

Then I want to insert: copied_id, new id, new name, and return it into the c#.

**For example:**

**Ads_Table**

```
adId   |    Name    |   Status    |  Date
------------------------------------------
 2g3   |    abc     |     3       |  03.10
 2g4   |    xyz     |     4       |  04.10
 2g5   |    123     |     4       |  03.10
```

assuming I have:

```
string[] adsIds = new string();
adsIds[0] = "2g3";
adsIds[1] = "2g5";

NewAdsDetails newAds = Duplicate_Ads(adsIds); // run the prosedure
```

the table will be:

**Ads_Table**

```
adId   |    Name    |   Status    |  Date
------------------------------------------
 2g3   |    abc     |     3       |  03.10
 2g4   |    xyz     |     4       |  04.10
 2g5   |    123     |     4       |  03.10
 gsd   |  abc_gsd   |     3       |  03.10 // this ad was copied
 hfs   |  123_hfs   |     4       |  03.10 // this ad was copied
```

The new Ids were generated by NEWID(), and the name was generated by: name of the copied 
adId + '_' + the newId of the new ad.

so the returned table will contains:

```
 copiedId, newAdId, newName
 --------------------------
 [2g3, gsd, abc_gsd;
  2g5, hfs, 123_hfs]
```

I tried to create the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Duplicate_Ads] @adsIds table(adId varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @newAdsIds table(adId varchar(20))
    DECLARE @newAdId NVARCHAR(100);


    DECLARE @Ad_cursor CURSOR;  
    SET @Ad_cursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM Ads_Table where adid in @AdsIds

    OPEN @Ad_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Ad_cursor INTO @newAdsIds ;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
        BEGIN
           BEGIN
             @newAdId = NEWID();
             INSERT INTO sensplit_ads values(@newAdId, Name + '_' + @newAdId, Status, date);
           END

           FETCH NEXT FROM @Ad_cursor INTO adId, @newAdId, Name + '_' + @newAdId;

       END

       CLOSE @Ad_cursor;
       DEALLOCATE @Ad_cursor;
       Return @newAdsIds;
END
```

so again, I want to write a procedure:

1. Get an array of string.
2. Duplicate all the ads that their Id are found in the given array, but generates new Id and new name for the new recored.
3. Return a table of: `copied_id`, `new Id`, and `new Name`.

any help appreciated!!

Comment: 1. Don't use cursors.

Comment: Instead of declaring a varchar parameter for the stored proc, declare a table parameter and pass in a table with the list of IDs to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @FreshPrinceOfSO said, don't use cursors if you can at all avoid them.  Something like the below should work (I can't test without actual data).  I used your NEWID() idea to generate the new id's, but I think it's not a good idea...  NEWID is for guids, not 3-character id's.   There is no guarantee of uniqueness when taking only three characters from NEWID.  You should be using integers (IDENTITY values) as unique IDs.

```
;WITH NewAds as (
    SELECT  a1.adId AS CopiedId
            , a1.Name AS CopiedName
            , RIGHT(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36)), 3) AS newAdId
    FROM    Ads_Table a1
            JOIN @AdsIds a2 ON a1.adId = a2.adId
)
SELECT  CopiedId, newAdId, CopiedName + '_' + newAdId AS [newName]
FROM    NewAds;
```